# Smart way to create n dimensional lattice of tuples from n 1-d numpy arrays and operate on each lattice points?

Tags: python, numpy, tuples, zip, list-comprehension

How to create an n dimensional lattice from n 1-d numpy arrays of dissimilar sizes. Meaning, imagine each lattice point contains a tuple of n numbers: small example:
lets have `n=3`, and `a = np.array([1,2,3])`, `b = np.array([4,5])`, `c = np.array([8,10])`, so I would want a 3x2x2 structure with the points have elements (1,4,8), (1,4,10), ... , (3,5,10) in *regular* order. What will be a smart way to achieve this for large sized `a`, `b`, `c` (also maybe n) and do operations on each tuple (like compare if any two entries of a tuple are *close* for each tuple).

Comment: For that purpose I'd use a numpy object, say
`lattice = np.empty(nt, dtype='object')`

Comment: Please elaborate as an answer. Thanks in advance.

Comment: please provide a more explicit example of what you want to do

Comment: First, I need (maybe, tuples) of each element with every other possible element from other arrays. What I need beyond that is an efficient method that returns how many of these tuples have at least two elements which are consecutive numbers.

Comment: @mozway can I know what exactly is missing/unclear/inconsistent

Comment: @Peedaruos you could provide a clear explicit output for starters

Answer (score 1):

```
    In [254]: a = np.array([1,2,3]); b = np.array([4,5]); c = np.array([8,10])
```

`meshgrid` can generate the values - as a tuple of arrays:

```
    In [255]: xyz = np.meshgrid(a,b,c, indexing='ij')
    In [256]: xyz
    Out[256]: 
    [array([[[1, 1],
             [1, 1]],
     
            [[2, 2],
             [2, 2]],
     
            [[3, 3],
             [3, 3]]]),
     array([[[4, 4],
             [5, 5]],
     
            [[4, 4],
             [5, 5]],
     
            [[4, 4],
             [5, 5]]]),
     array([[[ 8, 10],
             [ 8, 10]],
     
            [[ 8, 10],
             [ 8, 10]],
     
            [[ 8, 10],
             [ 8, 10]]])]
```

Joining them into one array:

```
    In [257]: np.stack(xyz, axis=3)
    Out[257]: 
    array([[[[ 1,  4,  8],
             [ 1,  4, 10]],
    
            [[ 1,  5,  8],
             [ 1,  5, 10]]],
    
    
           [[[ 2,  4,  8],
             [ 2,  4, 10]],
    
            [[ 2,  5,  8],
             [ 2,  5, 10]]],
    
    
           [[[ 3,  4,  8],
             [ 3,  4, 10]],
    
            [[ 3,  5,  8],
             [ 3,  5, 10]]]])
```

Flattening the first dimensions:

```
In [258]: np.reshape(_,(-1,3))
Out[258]: 
array([[ 1,  4,  8],
       [ 1,  4, 10],
       [ 1,  5,  8],
       [ 1,  5, 10],
       [ 2,  4,  8],
       [ 2,  4, 10],
       [ 2,  5,  8],
       [ 2,  5, 10],
       [ 3,  4,  8],
       [ 3,  4, 10],
       [ 3,  5,  8],
       [ 3,  5, 10]])
```

with a common Python tool:

```
In [260]: from itertools import product
In [261]: ijk = list(product(a,b,c))
In [262]: ijk
Out[262]: 
[(1, 4, 8),
 (1, 4, 10),
 (1, 5, 8),
 (1, 5, 10),
 (2, 4, 8),
 (2, 4, 10),
 (2, 5, 8),
 (2, 5, 10),
 (3, 4, 8),
 (3, 4, 10),
 (3, 5, 8),
 (3, 5, 10)]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
nt = 100
lattice = np.empty(nt, dtype='object')
lattice[0] = np.array([1,2,3])
lattice[1] = np.array([4,5])
lattice[2] = np.array([8,10])
```